# Haskell: simplifying a mutable vector type signature provided by :t

Tags: haskell

I can compile the following, but when I use `:t qsort` I get the long, complex type signature below. However, when I add that, the program will no longer type check, without additional imports (see answer below). My best guess at defining the type is also pasted below, but doen't type check (types and monads are bewildering).

Ok, so I could add an extra import statement and it type checks, but I've never seen a code signature this complex on any code published online. So my question is:

- I can drop `Ord t` and exhange `Int` for `t` and it checks, but how do I substitute in `ST` or `IO` for `Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad`, and what do I do with `v`.

I'm trying to write a [blog post](http://simonh1000.github.io/) that provides an example of how to use these various Monads, and by contrast for Arrays the type signature of qsort is a more manageable `qsort :: (STArray s Int Int) -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()`.  (For those that want to understand `s` there are lots of explanations on line, all of which passed slightly above my head - I get that it is a clever trick to get the type checker itself to prevent the author writing code where data from the Monad leaks out and thus leads to impurity.)

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as MV

main = do
    lines <- BS.lines `fmap` BS.readFile "10.txt"
    let
        inputData = Prelude.map (maybe (error "can't read Int") fst . BS.readInt) lines
        initialImmutableVector = V.fromList inputData

    print $ runST $ do
        state <- V.thaw initialImmutableVector
        qsort state 0 (Prelude.length inputData - 1)
        frozen <- V.freeze state
        return frozen

--qsort :: (MV.MVector s Int) -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
--qsort
--  :: (Ord t, Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m, MV.MVector v t) =>
--     v (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) t -> Int -> Int -> m ()
qsort vec min mx =
    if mx - min < 1 then
        return ()

    else do
        p <- MV.read vec min
        final_i <- foldM (partitioner p) (min+1) [(min+1)..mx]
        swap min (final_i - 1)
        qsort vec min     (final_i-2)
        qsort vec final_i mx     

    where
        swap i j = do
            vec_i <- MV.read vec i
            vec_j <- MV.read vec j
            MV.write vec i vec_j
            MV.write vec j vec_i

        partitioner p i acc = do
            vec_acc <- MV.read vec acc
            if vec_acc > p then
                return i
            else do
                swap i acc
                return $ i+1
```

Comment: Unlike in some ml languages, in Haskell you can't simply refer to a value (or type, any identifier really) fully qualified, you must import it first.

Comment: Note that the `Data.Vector.X.Mutable` modules export an `MV.swap` defined your way (but with a bounds check) https://github.com/haskell/vector/blob/master/Data/Vector/Generic/Mutable.hs#L730 .  It will probably be best either to scrap `Data.Vector` and use `Data.Vector.Generic`, so that the whole module is generic, or else use `Unboxed` for both mutable and immutable vectors, so that they whole module is specialized to the (especially valuable) `Unboxed` types. You generally import a matched pair of modules, one with `.Mutable` attached.  `Data.Vector` itself is not so great as the others.

Comment: I think what is disturbing you is just that in addition to type classes, `primitive` and `vector` use type functions, which do add another layer of complexity.

Comment: @Arthur I think you are correct. I can't learn everything at once, so is there a simpler type signature that it is easier to read that would provide a mutable vector of Ints?

Comment: If you omit `Generic`, doing `import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV` instead, then you can write either `qsort :: MV.STVector s Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()` or `qsort :: MV.IOVector Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()`.  The latter would not fit with `main` as you have it, since it uses `runST`. The former is the same as `qsort :: MV.MVector s Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()`, you original 'short' signature.

Comment: @Arthur that's my accepted answer!

Comment: Note that `Int` is an unboxed type, so you can do `import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V` `import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV`. In typical cases this will massively improve performance.

Comment: Wow - thanks. I need to learn about timing execution at some stage too...

Answer (score 4):

Importing function(-s) does not import their types. If your code explicitly refers to the type, it has to be imported. You can use imported functions without importing the types of their arguments or return values as long as the code does not explicitly refer to those types. Once you start using types or classes explicitly, you have to import them, this is intentional.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your last attempt is correct, but perhaps you didn't import everything you needed? The code you pasted as-is doesn't compile with or without type signatures. Here's a very slightly modified version of what you have that works just fine for me (with GHC 7.8.3):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimState, PrimMonad)
import Prelude hiding (lines, min)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lines <- BS.lines `fmap` BS.readFile "10.txt"
    let
        inputData = map (maybe (error "can't read Int") fst . BS.readInt) lines
        initialImmutableVector = V.fromList inputData

    print $ runST $ do
        state <- V.thaw initialImmutableVector
        qsort state 0 (Prelude.length inputData - 1)
        frozen <- V.freeze state
        return frozen

qsort :: (Ord t, PrimMonad m, MV.MVector v t)
      => v (PrimState m) t -> Int -> Int -> m ()
qsort vec min mx =
    if mx - min < 1 then
        return ()

    else do
        p <- MV.read vec min
        final_i <- foldM (partitioner p) (min+1) [(min+1)..mx]
        swap min (final_i - 1)
        qsort vec min     (final_i-2)
        qsort vec final_i mx     

    where
        swap i j = do
            vec_i <- MV.read vec i
            vec_j <- MV.read vec j
            MV.write vec i vec_j
            MV.write vec j vec_i

        partitioner p i acc = do
            vec_acc <- MV.read vec acc
            if vec_acc > p then
                return i
            else do
                swap i acc
                return $ i+1
```

Comment: Yes, but what is the more readable version - I've never seen a type signature that complex in books or on web tutorials?

Comment: Well, it just doesn't get any more readable than that unless you specialize to IO. ST does a rank-2 type trick to guarantee that the state of a ST action is inaccessible from the rest of the program, so its type signatures get complicated (either with an explicit forall or with this typeclass).